# Pygame joining 2 surfaces together

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to add a text surface to a bigger text surface. but I can't figure out how. In my case, the text surfaces are right next to each other but I want to make them one. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do but I don't know the correct formatting/command.

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont(font, size)

text_surf1 = font.render(string1, True, black)
text_surf2 = font.render(string2, True, black)

text_surf1 += text_surf2


gameDisplay.blit(text_surf3, (x,y))
```

Answer (score 8):

There's no function to combine two surfaces, but you can create another [`pygame.Surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html), pass the sum of the widths of the first two surfaces and then blit them onto the third surface.

```
txt1 = font.render(string1, True, black)
txt2 = font.render(string2, True, black)

# Create a surface and pass the sum of the widths.
# Also, pass pg.SRCALPHA to make the surface transparent.
txt3 = pg.Surface((txt1.get_width() + txt2.get_width(), txt1.get_height()), pg.SRCALPHA)

# Blit the first two surfaces onto the third.
txt3.blit(txt1, (0, 0))
txt3.blit(txt2, (txt1.get_width(), 0))
```

You could also just blit the two surfaces next to each other onto the `gameDisplay` unless you want to do something else with the combined surface.